# Difference between ParameterInfo.IsOptional and ParameterInfo.HasDefaultValue?

Tags: .net, reflection, default-value, optional-parameters, parameterinfo

They both sound similar. From msdn:

[ParameterInfo.IsOptional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isoptional.aspx)

> Gets a value indicating whether this parameter is optional.
>
> This method depends on an optional metadata flag. This flag can be
>   inserted by compilers, but the compilers are not obligated to do so.
>
> This method utilizes the Optional flag of the ParameterAttributes
>   enumerator.

[ParameterInfo.HasDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.hasdefaultvalue.aspx) (new in .NET 4.5)

> Gets a value that indicates whether this parameter has a default value.

Aren't they the same? I did quick test:

```
public void A(string value)
{

}
public void B(string value, int i = -1)
{

}
```

I wrote:

```
var a = AInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.HasDefaultValue).ToArray();
var b = AInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.IsOptional).ToArray();

var c = BInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.HasDefaultValue).ToArray();
var d = BInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.IsOptional).ToArray();

//a equals b; and c equals d
```

So in which context are they different? Why did BCL introduce `HasDefaultValue` in .NET 4.5 newly?

Comment: downvoter, please make it an answer if my question was stupid, or leave a comment so that I can ask questions in a better way

Comment: are you talking about PropertyInfo (title) or ParameterInfo (question) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we look at the implementation of `IsOptional` we will see:

```
public bool IsOptional
{
  [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
  {
    return (this.Attributes & ParameterAttributes.Optional) != ParameterAttributes.None;
  }
}
```

It depends on a metadata flag, but as it is written in the msdn:

> This method depends on an optional metadata flag. This flag can be inserted by compilers, but the compilers are not obligated to do so.

This means that it depends on the compiler and if we use other compiler, we can get that parameter that has default value will not have `IsOptional` flag.
Now let's see how HasDefaultValue property implemented:

```
public override bool HasDefaultValue
{
  get
  {
    if (this.m_noMetadata || this.m_noDefaultValue)
      return false;
    else
      return this.GetDefaultValueInternal(false) != DBNull.Value;
  }
}
```

It always checks whether the parameter has default value and does not depend on the compiler. This may not be a 100% correct answer, just my thoughts.

**UPDATE 0**

Here's example where parameter has not default value but `IsOptional` is true:

```
public static void Method([Optional]string parameter)
{
}

ParameterInfo parameterInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method").GetParameters()[0];
//Is true
bool isOptional = parameterInfo.IsOptional;
//Is false
bool hasDefaultValue = parameterInfo.HasDefaultValue;
```

Comment: Yes, `HasDefaultValue` is the way to go, but in .NET 4, you can go the `p.Attributes & ParameterAttributes.HasDefault` way

Comment: `ParameterAttributes.HasDefault` also depends on the compiler.

Comment: What do you mean by *It is not 100% correct answer is just my thoughts.*?

Comment: You asked why they did it? I can not answer exactly why they made so I can only assume.

Comment: Ah now I get it, but your wording was no so clear. Pls find my edit

Comment: Did you test that? You can use the same code you have shown to do so: `bool hasDefaultValue = (parameterInfo.Attributes & ParameterAttributes.HasDefault) == ParameterAttributes.HasDefault;`. Returns false

Comment: In my example is return false, because the compiler did not added this flag. If you read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isoptional(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that this attribute set manually: `// Set the attribute for the third parameter to OPTIONAL.
      myParameterBuilder = myMethodBuilder.DefineParameter(3, ParameterAttributes.Optional | ParameterAttributes.HasDefault, "MyLongParameter");` and it depends on the compiler.

Comment: Yes it should return false (thats what I said in my comment), because it is essentially a .NET 4 way of checking it instead of `HasDefaultValue` of .NET 4.5. Since your parameter is only optional, without any default value it returns false. It will return true when your parameter is not optional (which also means there is no default value)

Answer (score 3):

Danny Chen and vvs0205 state the difference exactly, that `IsOptional` is always compiler dependent and to check if the parameter is an optional parameter *whose default value is specified* use `HasDefaultValue`.

```
bool isOptional = parameterInfo.IsOptional;

bool isOptionalWithADefaultValue = parameterInfo.HasDefaultValue; //.NET 4.5

bool isOptionalWithADefaultValue = (p.Attributes & ParameterAttributes.HasDefault) == ParameterAttributes.HasDefault; //.NET 4 and below
```

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977530/default-parameters-and-reflection-if-parameterinfo-isoptional-then-is-defaultva) (*catch some other undocumented techniques to get the same in that thread*)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the conclusion "they are the same" using "a equals b; and c equals d", like:

```
int[] a = new[] { 0, 1, 5 };
var c = a.Where(n => n < 2).ToArray();
var d = a.Where(n => n < 3).ToArray();  
//you can't say "2 == 3" even c equals to d in sequence
```

Ok back to the topic, *currently* an optional parameter always has a default value, this conclusion is correct "by now". But AFAIK it's undocumented behavior, which means the compiler may change its behavior/implementation to optional parameters. So if you want to check(via reflection) if the parameter is an optional one, use `.IsOptional` property. If you want to check if it has a default value(maybe marked by some attribute e.g. DefaultValue? just maybe), use `.HasDefaultValue` property. Sounds like superfluous words but it's true.

Comment: I got it, and I know `2 == 3` cant be made out of it, surely :) (I overlooked it). That's why I made it a question. I just stated a scenario I could think of where `HasDefaultValue` could be different to `IsOptional` but did not prove to be so. So asked the community since it din sound as conclusive as a rudimentary `2 != 3` :)